# Add values from promise.all to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, promise.all

I am invoking multiple api calls using Promise.all and am able to receive their responses, but I want to add them to an array

my code

```js
async function asynchUploadGrpFiles(files) {
  var responseDetails = [];

  await Promise.all([get('https://httpbin.org/get?a=1'),
    get('https://httpbin.org/get?b=2'),
    get('https://httpbin.org/get?c=3')
  ]).then(values => {

    responseDetails.push(":::: time :::" + values);

    console.log(values);
  });

  console.log(responseDetails.toString());
}
```

I am able to log the response from `console.log(values);`, but these are not getting pushed in `responseDetails`

Comment: Why do you use `async`/`await`?

Comment: @Andreas I want this function to be called asynchronously

Comment: Why call something asynchronously that doesn't return anything useful?

Comment: @Andreas you are not being helpful here. OP seems to be confused between `async/await` and `then` syntaxes. I believe he is able to get response asynchronously as he mentioned. Could you justify the close?

Comment: "*I want to add them to an array*" - `values` already *is* an array. Just use it. Also I'd recommend `const values = await Promise.all(…);` instead of using `then` syntax.

Comment: The answer should work for most of the scenarios. We cannot had-code the response and accept it as a solution.

Comment: @Bergi it is printing a blank array

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala What scenarios are you talking about? Where is a response hard-coded? What should it depend on? It's really unclear what you are trying to generalise here.

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala What do you mean by "blank array"? An empty array? Then you didn't pass any promises to `Promise.all`. Or an array of `undefined` values? Then the promises returned by your `get` calls didn't fulfill with anything.

Comment: @Bergi "blank array" mean " An empty array", my promise is returning me the expected response, because I am able to log in using ".then (value => {console.log (value) });

Comment: You cannot use both `await` and a `then` callback that doesn't return anything. Use only `const values = await Promise.all(…); console.log(values); …`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
const asynchUploadGrpFiles = async (files) => {
  const [data1, data2, data3] = await Promise.all([
    get('https://httpbin.org/get?a=1'),
    get('https://httpbin.org/get?b=2'),
    get('https://httpbin.org/get?c=3'),
  ])
  const responseDetails = [...data1, ...data2, ...data3]
  console.log(responseDetails.toString())
}
```

Then to call the function

```
// Call it somewhere
await asynchUploadGrpFiles(files)
```

Comment: how can I generalise this

Comment: Can you let me know what you what you mean by that?

Comment: What if, I have a dynamic number of entries in Promise.all. Currently I have 3, what if I have more that 3

Comment: I think thats a whole other question. Please mark this as the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala Create an array, put promises in it dynamically, then call `Promise.all` on it.